# Is distributed file storage(HDFS/Cassandra/S3 etc.) mandatory for spark to run in clustered mode? if yes, why?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

Is distributed file storage(HDFS/Cassandra/S3 etc.) mandatory for spark to run in clustered mode? if yes, why?

Spark is distributed data processing engine used for computing huge volumes of data. Let's say I have huge volume of data stored in mysql which I want to perform processing on. Spark reads the data from mysql and perform in-memory (or disk) computation on the cluster nodes itself. I am still not able to understand why is distributed file storage needed to run spark in a clustered mode?

Comment: You could try Presto instead of Spark if you want distributed SQL processing

Answer (score 1):

> is distributed file storage(HDFS/Cassandra/S3 etc.) mandatory for spark to run in clustered mode?

Pretty Much

> if yes, why?

Because the spark workers take input from a shared table, distribute the computation amongst themselves, then are choreographed by the spark driver to write their data back to another shared table.

If you are trying to work exclusively with mysql you *might* be able to use the local filesystem ("file://) as the cluster FS. However, if any RDD or stage in a spark query does try to use a shared filesystem as a way of committing work, the output isn't going to propagate from the workers (which will have written to their local filesystem) and the spark driver (which can only read its local filesystem)

Comment: You mean that to perform computations, spark needs to store some intermediate results in some storage so that other nodes in the cluster can read from the shared file system. Otherwise, spark would need to send this intermediate data to all the nodes who might need it which would require quite a lot of network IO and would slow the processing. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Start by reading the RDD paper: https://www.usenix.org/conference/nsdi12/technical-sessions/presentation/zaharia  . The nodes do all cache data and pass it around "the shuffle", but classic filesystem I/O does need a shared, distributed FS. Pure MySQL IO? you'll have to try and see

Comment: Thanks for sharing the paper.. I read it and sorry for my late reply.. Let me share my current scenario with you.. I have some data stored in cassandra tables.. my spark job would read the data from cassandra.. perform some computations on it and then store the data back in cassandra (in different table(s))... my spark job would run on a separate cluster.. now in this scenario.. Do I really need distributed FS such as HDFS/S3, etc.? As per details mentioned in the paper you shared, I can't figure out the reason why distributed FS would be needed in this scenario

Comment: you should be able to work directly with cassandra -but you'd need to check to be sure. Ask on the Apache cassandra or Apache spark usergroups for the most up to date answer. SO answers age badly as nobody ever updates them as the world changes